# Google+ in iOS 9.3 is hanging up

Tags: ios, google-plus, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the share option in my app using `UIActivityViewController`; it's working fine in iOS 9.2 and Google+ share option is not working in iOS 9.3

To confirm this, I had downloaded other app which has the share option using `UIActivityViewController`, and the issue is the entire UI of the app is hanging up.

How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit 1:**
*code:*

```
        NSURL * URL =  [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domainName/message.php?"];

        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSString *tempEmailId  = (NSString *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:CURRENT_USER_EMAIL_ID_UD_KEY];
        NSString *tempPassword = (NSString *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:CURRENT_USER_PASSWORD_UD_KEY];

        NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", tempEmailId, tempPassword];
       [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];
       //NSLog(@"request %@\n",request);
       [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (data != nil) {
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSArray * activityItems = @[responseString];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:activities];
                [activityViewController setValue:@"Today's Recommendations" forKey:@"subject"];
                activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook];

[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:
                 ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     NSLog(@"activityType: %@, returnedItems: %@, activityError: %@", activityType, returnedItems, activityError.userInfo);

                     if (completed)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"The Activity: %@ was completed", activityType);
                     }
                    else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"The Activity: %@ was NOT completed", activityType);
                     }
                     });

                 }];

                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
//if iPad
                else {
                    activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

                    // activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender;

                    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

                    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
                        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = btn.frame;
                    }

                    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            });
        }
    }] resume];
```

**NOTE:**: Mail, Twitter, and Evernote are working. Only Google+ is hanging up.

**Edit 2:**: I don't know exactly but I think- its not related to open URL. If it's related then please let me know HOW?

Comment: Related?  [iOS 9.3 freeze after calling openURL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36257922/2415822)  @AashishBhatnagar are you calling `openURL`?

Comment: @Lion, please, post the code snippet you involve, which leads to irresponsiveness of iOS?

Comment: @Lion, Have you added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist file?

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes sir, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
</plist>

Answer (score 3):

Some JavaScript problems occurred in iOS 9.3. Its clearly mentioned in below article. Its not a code problem, it's an Apple webview problem. Check attached quote and URL for your reference.

> #### iOS 9.3 freezes when clicking a link in an email
>
> One of the most common problems ... affects links in emails. When using iOS 9.3, some people have found that by clicking a link in the Mail email app, the iPhone or iPad will become unresponsive.
>
> ***A temporary solution is to turn off JavaScript in the Safari app by going to Settings > Safari > Advanced then turn off the toggle next to JavaScript.***
>
> ***This solution isn't ideal, and thankfully Apple has pushed out a new update, iOS 9.3.1 which according to the release notes "fixes an issue that caused apps to be unresponsive after tapping on links in Safari and other apps."***
>
> To download and install the update open up Settings and select General then Software Update. You should now be able to turn JavaScript back on and can click on links in emails and other messages without iOS 9.3 freezing.

Reference Link: [iOS 9.3 Problems](http://www.in.techradar.com/how-to/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/iOS-9-3-problems-Heres-how-to-fix-the-most-common-issues/articleshow/51530998.cms)

Comment: Sir, My iPad have iOS 9.3.1 version

Comment: Yes I understood. same issue still not resolved. me also facing this problem in my app and also safari. after contact developer support they told this issue will resolve soon.

Comment: Hmm sure. Me also waiting..

Comment: No.... Still have the same problem.